# validation error in node.js using postman mongodb in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, postman

I had task to make new service using post man I have written module controller and routes code but unfortunately when I send mission to create object using postman it gives me validation error and I have no idea what it is
[image]

I know that validation error means that problem is in module but I cant figure out what it wants

Comment: `post_id` is required in your mongoose schema. Are you sending the post_id with Postman ?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have made`post_id` as required field so,when you are creating document you are missing `post_id` in your `req.body`.So you have to either send `post_id` in body or if you don't want to save `post_id` every document them you can remove `required:true` from your model.